# creating a simple php web service using nusoap

Tags: php

i want to display the server's data in multiple rows to the client side. The current implementation shows only one row i.e. value of 'ABC' to client
Here is the server side:

```
<?php
    function getStockQuote($symbol) {

        mysql_connect('server','user','pass');
        mysql_select_db('test');
        $query = "SELECT stock_price FROM stockprices "
               . "WHERE stock_symbol = '$symbol'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['stock_price'];
    }

    require('nusoap.php');

    $server = new soap_server();

    $server->configureWSDL('stockserver', 'urn:stockquote');

    $server->register("getStockQuote",
                    array('symbol' => 'xsd:string'),
                    array('return' => 'xsd:decimal'),
                    'urn:stockquote',
                    'urn:stockquote#getStockQuote');

    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)
                          ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

And here is the client side:

```
<?php
    require_once('nusoap.php');

    $c = new soapclient('http://localhost/stockserver.php');

    $stockprice = $c->call('getStockQuote',
              array('symbol' => 'ABC'));

    echo "The stock price for 'ABC' is $stockprice.";

?>
```

Comment: Post the error please after changes suggested

Comment: i want to return mutliple rows from the server to the client, how can i do that? pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify an WSDL as endpoint, so change the endpoint with the wsdl, and need to call to your method (`call` method doesn't exist on your server)

My client code that i test and works:

```
<?php
require_once('nusoap.php');

$c = new soapclient('http://localhost/stockserver.php?wsdl');

$stockprice = $c->getStockQuote('ABC');
echo "The stock price for 'ABC' is $stockprice.";

?>
```

And please **stop using deprecated mysql_* functions**

Comment: See my edited answer, first error says that cannot find a wsdl file,if you don't change the `call` method then says that theres no method `call`

Comment: I tried with my changes and it works perfectly (y use return "Hello" in server method). Note: I changed again to avoid a Notice error

Comment: made the above suggested change.. the error is still there ,   isnt it related with the nusoap file , i'm actually using php 5.3.5

Comment: sorry , was trying some different ways.. and now it shows  'The stock price for 'ABC' is' and perhaps the call to $stockprice = $c->call('getStockQuote',array('symbol' => 'ABC')); is not taking place

Comment: Change your client code with mine, as i explained you have to call to the method `getStockQuote` not to function `call` that doesn't exist

Comment: ohh!! i removed that 'call' , actually i had to change  $c = new nusoapclient('http://localhost/stockserver.php'); to $c = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/stockserver.php'); and now  it shows Call to undefined method nusoap_client::getStockQuote()

Comment: and when i replace your code the error is : Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in C:\xampp\htdocs\stockclient.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\stockclient.php(6): SoapClient->__call('getStockQuote', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\stockclient.php(6): SoapClient->getStockQuote('ABC') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\stockclient.php on line 6

Comment: Well, that's correct, if you get this error then must be something wrong with the code of your method, if you change the code of the server method `getStockQuote` with `return "Hello"` you can see that is working well and the client prints `The stock price for 'ABC' is Hello.`, so, review your code with the server method

Comment: well sir as changes arent working.can you please do those server changes for me?...

Comment: I'm afraid no, i don't know your data, the problem is in the `getStockQuote` method is the only thing that i know... Test in a separated function or post another question. This question is for create a web service, and is solved, but the method isn't it. You cna post another question, explaining your model, what did you try, etc

Comment: i have tried many examples to read data from mysql server but they neither show any error nor give any output. for a simple web service in which we just display server's array values to client, runs perfectly but for database it doesnt happen. so can you please show a very short example to read data from database.

Comment: Search for some web tutorial like http://codular.com/php-mysqli and if you have some problem with it then post a NEW question. This question is solved

Comment: well sir as you said, the problem was in the server code and just few seconds ago i solved it thanx..

Comment: i want to return mutliple rows from the server to the client, how can i do that? pls help